# Как ускорить замену элементов в списке Python?

Tags: python, алгоритм, циклы, разработка-игр, оптимизация

Есть список mapping_pixels=[(68, 68, 125, 255), (68, 68, 125, 255), (71, 72, 86, 255), .....] в котором 1280*1280 элементов и есть список unique_pixels[] из множества уникальных элементов списка mapping_pixels[], коих 3800 шт. Надо все элементы списка mapping_pixels[] заменить на индекс элементов списка unique_pixels[], если значения совпадают.
Я сделал две итерации и сравниваю по элементу, но это очень долго. Подскажите способ что бы процесс не занимал много времени.

```py
from PIL import Image

def create_map2():
    im = Image.open('sprite/map3.png').convert('RGBA')
    mapping_pixels = list(im.getdata())
    mapping = []
    row = []
    unique_pixels = list(set(list(mapping_pixels)))
    step = 0
    unique_pixels_dict = {
        value: i
        for i, value in enumerate(unique_pixel)
    }
    for pixel in mapping_pixel:
        if len(row) == im.width:
            mapping.append(row)
            row = []
        row.append(unique_pixels_dict[pixel])
    return im.width, im.height, list(set(list(im.getdata()))), mapping

map2 = create_map2()
```

[image: Map]

Comment: Приведите ваш код в вопросе.

Comment: я бы посоветовал numpy попробовать. но не имея перед глазами пример исходных данных, конкретно сказать не могу.

Comment: 1 - что у вас в коде список a, а что - список b? 2 - замените список b на dict, где ключи - цвета, а значения - индексы. Тогда для поиска цвета не нужно будет проходить по всему b.

Comment: И не используйте `map` как имя переменной, это встроенная функция питона

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сударь, вам надо учиться задавать понятные вопросы :)

1. "тот же самый список b[] без повторения элементов в нём 3800 элементов" – это скорее не тот же самый, а "список b из множества уникальных элементов списка a, коих 3800 шт".
2. Чтобы упростить жизнь отвечающим, стоит связать вашу абстрактную формулировку вопроса с кодом, а не вынуждать перечитывать вопрос пару раз: список `a` в коде это `map_pixel`, а `b` это `l`.
3. `l` плохое название, я бы заменил на что-то более осмысленное вроде `unique_values`.
4. Насчёт плохой практики использования встроенных значений вроде `map` как имён переменных вам уже подсказали.

Проблема же здесь в том, что из-за вложенности циклов сложность алгоритма выходит квадратичной, что легко решается использованием словаря с маппингом значений из списка `b` в их индексы:

```py
map_pixels = list(...)
unique_values = list(set(map_pixels))
unique_values_indices = {
    value: i
    for i, value in enumerate(unique_values)
}

row = []
for pixel in map_pixels:
    row.append(unique_values_indices[pixel])
```

---

Кстати, "Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules", и ваш особый кейс с `(68, 68, 122, 255)` можно реализовать более грамотно:

```py
first_values = [(68, 68, 122, 255)]
unique_values = first_values + list(set(map_pixels) - set(first_values))
```

Таким образом, это особое значение всегда будет иметь нулевой индекс, зато не потребует отдельной обработки в цикле, а при желании эту штуку легко масштабировать добавив в список `first_values` дополнительные первые значения.

<sub>Привет собрату гейм-девелоперу</sub>

Comment: Спасибо, исправил. Попробую ещё Numpy добавить. Удачи в гейм-деве :)

Answer (score 0):

попробовал ускорить

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def create_map2():
    im = Image.open('sprite/map3.png').convert('RGBA')
    mapping_pixel = (list(im.getdata()))
    unique_pixel = (list(set(list(im.getdata()))))
    unique_pixel_dict = {
        value: i
        for i, value in enumerate(unique_pixel)
    }
    mapping = list(map(lambda x: unique_pixel_dict[x], mapping_pixel))
    mapping = np.array(mapping)
    mapping = self.mapping.reshape(im.height, im.width)

    return im.width, im.height, unique_pixel , mapping

map2 = create_map2()
```